Class type parameter Comparable and Nullable
Consider the following code:
val sureInt: Int = 7
val unsureInt: Int? = null

class LowControlGetter<T : Comparable<T>> {
    fun get(x: T?): T? = x
}

val workingWell: Int? = LowControlGetter<Int>().get(unsureInt)
val couldBeBetter: Int = LowControlGetter<Int>().get(sureInt)!! // you're nonnull, I know it

LowControlGetter can't know the 2nd Int is not null, because its T parameter doesn't track nullability, so I added that in:
class HighControlGetter<T : Comparable<T>?> { // what do I put as type parameter?
    fun get(x: T): T = x
}

val invalid: Int? = HighControlGetter<Int?>().get(unsureInt) // breaks
val working: Int = HighControlGetter<Int>().get(sureInt)

and now I can't find a type parameter that works:

T : Comparable<T>? is wrong because Int? can't compare Int?, fair
T : Comparable<T & Any>? is what I would conceptually want, but intellij says "Intersection types are only supported for definitely non-nullable types: left part should be a type parameter with nullable bounds"
T works, but in the real code I need T to satisfy Comparable<T>

The same exact assembly with functions works as expected:
val sureInt: Int = 7
val unsureInt: Int? = null

fun <T : Comparable<T>> lowControlGet(x: T?): T? = x

val workingWell: Int? = lowControlGet<Int>(unsureInt)
val couldBeBetter: Int = lowControlGet<Int>(sureInt)!! // you're nonnull, I know it

fun <T : Comparable<T & Any>?> highControlGet(x: T): T = x // it works like this

val working: Int? = highControlGet<Int?>(unsureInt)
val working: Int = highControlGet<Int>(sureInt)

Is this a limitation of the language or I'm missing a syntax trick?

It's hard to answer this without additional context about the LowControlGetter.get and its expected behavior. If the only thing you need is that it can accept a nullable T and then it returns exactly the same type, then you can make the function itself generic: fun <S : T?> get(x: S): S = x..

Yeah, the real code is more complicated, get is not a function, it's a reference to a lambda and I cannot make it generic.
But I need HighControlGetter<T> to really hold Int?, not hold Int and then adapt the class innards, as other stuff I care about depends on T.

I think I understand what you mean and yes, it seems like a limitation in the language. As a rule of thumb, if generics involve 2 types, then we need to parameterize over both of them - even if there is a relatively simple relationship between them. LowControlGetter<S : T?, T : Comparable<T>> should work, but I suppose you still prefer your simple LowControlGetter<Int>(), without a need to provide both types.
